# Splitting GeoTIFFs

Tags: qgis, orthophoto

I have three different GeoTIFF orthophotos I am trying to tile (the editing program I use can't accept the GeoTIFFs as is), and I would like to retain the geographical information. Can someone offer any tips?

Comment: Your title asks about splitting, but your question is about tiling.  If you include what you have tried, and how that didn't meet your need, it will be easier to recommend changes.

Comment: If you're editing in GIMP or Photoshop that will definitely destroy your georeference as the tags that these programs don't recognize are omitted on saving.. do you have any python ability? If not there's a utility call GeoTiff Examiner https://freegeographytools.com/2007/handling-tiff-worldfiles-with-geotiffexaminer that can export your georeference to a world file and then import it again from the world file when you're done editing. To tile an image from QGIS you could use raster::translate (GDAL_Translate) with a -projwin switch to export only part of the image.

Comment: There is a QGIS GDAL tool in the processing toolbox called Clip Raster by Extent.  You could section up your rasters manually using this tool.